# CSV file with multiple unwanted text in columns

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula

How would I remove all the strings after the letter T, assuming that this is Column A

```
2022-01-23T08:01
2022-06-15T09:01
2022-05-20T10:23
2022-04-30T11:02
```

---

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(A1, SEARCH("T", A1) - 1), A1)
```

but every time I try to copy it down it changes the figures instead of just removing the strings, in most cases it returns a 0.

Regards

Comment: Use `TEXTBEFORE(A1,"T")`

Comment: You probably meant to do: `=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(A1,"T")), A1, LEFT(A1,SEARCH(A1,"T")-1))` ?

Comment: @Luuk Sir, in your formula you need to wrap the `SEARCH()` function within or either `ISNUMBER()` or `ISERROR()` because when there is no `T` it would return an error, and then the `FALSE` argument won't work.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya: I just edited the formula (because it was indeed incorrect!) but now it should be correct!

Comment: Yes, btw OP can also use `TEXTBEFORE()` I have posted in answers.

Comment: If all data has the same format (and they are strings, not decmials, =left(A1,10) will work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using <kbd>TEXTBEFORE( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `B1`

```
=TEXTBEFORE(A1:A5,"T",,,1,A1:A5)+0
```

---

Or, Using <kbd>LEFT( )</kbd> and <kbd>FIND( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `C1`

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("T",A1)),A1+0,LEFT(A1,FIND("T",A1)-1)+0)
```

---

Or, Using <kbd>TEXTSPLIT( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `D1`

```
=TEXTSPLIT(A1:A5,"T")
```

---